# Is there some way to request peer review on an edit?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits

I just edited [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/353381/232393) answer, I just reached 2000+ reputation and the edit got immediately accepted. Is there some way to turn this off?

I´m fairly sure this was a good edit, but I have done bad edits before, like the one for [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/303623/232393) answer, where I removed all incorrect information, which was most of the answer. That edit was correctly rejecte by peer review, because *"This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."*

I learned from that and will try to avoid doing something like that again, this is not possible without peer review, I felt unsure about that edit, but didn´t know about that reason to reject it and thought it would be fine, because I only removed incorrect information.

I usually feel fairly sure about my edits, but there are some cases where I am unsure and where I would prefer to have someone else approve it via peer review.

Is there a feature like that? If not, then I would like to suggest such a feature. It could work similar to how the "community wiki" checkbox works, then I could tick a checkbox that sends the edit to the review queue, rather than being imidiately accepted, whenever I feel unsure about an edit, or simply don´t want to make a final decision, I´m not perfect, I make mistakes.

Adding a feature like that would make it possible to learn from mistakes, even at higher reputation levels. In my case I feel like it´s too early to ALWAYS have the edit accepted without peer review, because I´m still learning and I reached this much reputation too quickly to fully understand the rules. I´m bound to make mistakes and I don´t want anyone else to suffer for it.

I do feel confident enough to decide when an edit feels a bit risky though, so I think simply having the option to have an edit peer reviewed would be enough.

Alternatively I could just never make any edits if I´m not completely sure if they are good, but in that case I would no longer have the opportunity to learn if an edit is good, or not, so a lot of future edits that would be good would never be made, because I was unsure.

Comment: You could probably keep offering [bounties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) to keep yourself under 2K rep.  Otherwise, thanks for making the site better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't suggest reviews anymore now that you've reached 2000 reputation. The system (and the users who voted for your posts) trusts you to have learned how editing works by now, by having your suggested edits approved or rejected, and by seeing the edits of other users who have earned the same privilege as you.

And frankly, the system seems to be working as expected! You've noticed that some of your edits were rejected, and have learned why. But as everyone knows, with great power comes great responsibility. Now that you can edit posts without having your changes approved by other users, you should only make edits that you're feeling confident about.

Similar feature requests have popped up from time to time on Meta Stack Exchange, like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231504/how-do-i-opt-out-of-privileges). It doesn't look like revoking your own privileges is going to be implemented.

Comment: I am ok with this for the most part and I can't make any arguments that haven't been made before. I would try to very rarely, if at all, use a feature like this, but it would be a great feature to have for those rare cases where I do think it is better to suggest an edit, rather than to just edit a post.

Comment: @Mr.Bear you can always make a minor edit instead of a big one that you're unsure of. The question will appear on the homepage, so it will get more attention, and you can comment on the post so either the OP or a viewer tell you what they have in mind, or even edit the post themselves.

Comment: @Quijibo That is a kind of a solution, though "Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged" according to the help center (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @Mr.Bear FWIW I gather that there is quite an active chat community here so you could always ask in chat for guidance. Another possibility is to leave a comment on the post about the edit or even before you edit to see if it appropriate. And lastly remember that you don't have to edit, if you are all that unsure just don't edit.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot As I said above, I do feel confident about my edits, this feature would mainly be if I am unsure if an edit is still within the bounds of what an edit should do. Usually those are the questions where I feel the strongest need to edit them, which is why I would want to make big edits. Not editing them would feel like a bad thing, because as I said, those are the post where I feel like they need it the most. Commenting would work, but it would be much simpler and more efficient to send it to the review queue, because I basically make the full edit and then ask "is this ok?".

Comment: @Mr.Bear Well asking in chat, link to the post and include your revised version, is a decent workaround for this if you are unsure.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot What chat in particular should I use and how do I include my revised version without actually making the edit?

Comment: @Mr.Bear I'm not really an Arqade regular but I gather that [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) is the main chatroom so probably ask in there, but I would get advise from a chat regular before doing so. You can include the revised version by either simply copy and pasting it or including a screenshot whichever makes more sense (usually the former).

Answer (score 4):

Wrigglenite's answer covers the feature request side of things so I'll just address the act of editing itself:

> Is there some way to request peer review on an edit?

You already are!...kinda. Every edit you make bumps that question to the front page, complete with a little 'modified by <UserName>' message and link that takes users directly to the post you edited. So in a way, your edits are *still* pushed up to be reviewed by the community. All that's changed is that we trust you enough to make those edits *immediately*, instead of first holding them back for community review.

> I´m still learning and I reached this much reputation too quickly to fully understand the rules. I´m bound to make mistakes and I don´t want anyone else to suffer for it.

You'll be fine. It may seem daunting, but don't fret - edits are important, but are fairly trivial to change, update, or roll back - there's not a whole lot that can go terribly wrong. If it helps, the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) gives some general guidance:

> ## When should I edit posts?
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> **Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

---

If you feel it's a good edit, go ahead and make the judgement call. If you miss something, or introduce a typo etc, someone else will just edit it again, or (worst case) roll it back. You can see all your revisions on your profile ([here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=revisions)), so if you want to check back a day or two later and see if anything changed, you can.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when in doubt just don't edit. If it's a new post and on the homepage someone will probably get it at some point.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I usually err on the side of asking forgiveness over permission. If I'm unsure about an edit I'll leave a comment for the OP along the lines of *"Here's what I changed and how I came to the conclusion, feel free to edit or rollback if that is not correct :)"*. In my experience it has been a generally positive outcome whether or not the edit was kept - most people are just grateful that someone cared enough to improve the post.

Comment: To be honest on SFF I usually do the same thing, and it's good practice to leave comments with edits anyway (depending on the edit of course). However, the OP here seems quite unsure and if you're that unsure it might be worth checking first. Either work but do have their pros and cons.